# Como realizar um insert apartir de um select em uma tabela de outra base de dados PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho duas bases de dados e tenho uma tabela **TabelaX** na base de dados **Servidor1** sem dados e outra base de dados **Servidor2** com uma tabela **TabelaY**. E eu quero fazer um `select` na tabela **TabelaY** e com seus dados faço um `insert` na tabela **TabelaX** que fica em outra base de dados. Eu já fiz algum código, mas não está funcionando corretamente. E esse erro aparece:

```
Error: INSERT INTO Servidor1.TabelaX (ID, Data) SELECT ID, Data FROM 
Servidor2.TabelaY; VALUES (4, 918745125);
Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Procurar Dados</h2>
      <?php
         echo "<h3> Clientes </h3>";

         // Criar conexao 
         $conn= mysqli_connect('localhost','root',null,'Servidor2') or die (mysqli_connect_error());

         //Verificar conexao 
         if (!$conn) {
            die("Falha de conexao: ". mysqli_connect_error());
         }
         $ID = $_POST['ID'];
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM TabelaY WHERE ID = $ID";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         mysqli_select_db($conn,"Servidor1");

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 $row1 = $row["ID"];
                 $row2 = $row["Data"];

             }
         } else {
             echo "0 results";
         }

         $sql = "INSERT INTO Servidor1.TabelaX (ID, Data)
                    SELECT ID, Data
                    FROM Servidor2.TabelaY;
                     VALUES ($row1, $row2);";
                     if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
                         echo "Dados Inseridos";
                     } else {
                         echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                     }


         mysqli_close($conn);


         ?>
      <p> </p>
      <a href="http://localhost/BaseDados/Index.html">
      Voltar à entrada </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O VALUES esta errado, não precisa utilizar.

INSERT INTO Servidor1.TabelaX (ID, Data) (SELECT ID, Data FROM Servidor2.TabelaY);

Comment: Esta a aparecer este erro: Error: INSERT INTO Servidor1.TabelaX (ID, Data) SELECT ID, Data FROM Servidor2.TabelaY;
Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'